# Touch event working but not expected output

Tags: android

```
alpha_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         int action=event.getAction();

         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (action)
         {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         {
         // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
         next();
         break;
         }
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         {
         // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
         previous();
         break;
         }
         }
         return false;
         }
         });
```

This is the code I used for image move by finger touch but it is working oneside 
(only moving left side) can someone please help me to move image right side also ,that is based on the user touch the image need to move.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't supply your next() and previous() methods.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you misunderstood the concepts of ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN (or you just trying to create some very customized UI) but nevertheless, you should return `true` after intercepting ACTION_DOWN in order ACTION_UP to get fired when you lift your finger.